# Error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony

I have a read a lot of topics on this and I can't seem to find a solution to my problem.
The error is FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object in in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php at line 291.

```
public function getDoctrine()
{
    if (!$this->container->has('doctrine')) {
        throw new \LogicException('The DoctrineBundle is not   registered in your application.');
    }
```

}

This is the main controller

```
namespace Acme\IndexBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Acme\IndexBundle\Entity\SlotmachineSpin;
use Acme\IndexBundle\Entity\SlotmachineReels;
use Acme\IndexBundle\Entity\SlotmachinePrizes;
use Acme\IndexBundle\Slots\UsersSlots;
use Acme\IndexBundle\Slots\SlotsMachineSlots;


class SpinController extends Controller  {


    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $slotsmachine = new SlotsMachineSlots();
        //$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $_machineName = $request->request->get('machine_name');
        $machineName = $slotsmachine->GetMachineName((isset($_machineName)?$_machineName : "default" ));
        $_bet = $request->request->get('bet');
        $bet = (isset($_bet) ? $_bet : $slotsmachine->MinBet($machineName)); // Should always be set, but just in case.
        $bet = min(max($slotsmachine->MinBet($machineName), $bet), $slotsmachine->MaxBet($machineName));
        $_windowID = $request->request->get('windowID');
        $windowID = (isset($_windowID) ? $_windowID : "");

        // Validate
        $error = "";
        $userID = UsersSlots::LoggedUserID();

        try { //DB::BeginTransaction();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

            if (!$userID) {
                $error = 'loggedOut';
            } else if(!UsersSlots::HasEnoughCredits($userID, $bet)) {
                $error = "You don't have enough credits for this bet";
            }

            if ($error != "") {
                echo json_encode(array('success'=>false, 'error'=>$error));
                return;
            }

            // Do the charging, spinning and crediting
            UsersSlots::DeductCredits($userID, $bet);

            UsersController::IncrementSlotMachineSpins($userID);
            $data = SlotsMachineSlots::Spin($userID, $machineName, $bet, $windowID);

            if ($data['prize'] != null) {
                UsersSlots::IncreaseCredits($userID, $data['prize']['payoutCredits']);
                UsersSlots::IncreaseWinnings($userID, $data['prize']['payoutWinnings']);
                $data['lastWin'] = $data['prize']['payoutWinnings'];
            }

            $data['success'] = true;

            $userData = UsersSlots::GetUserData($userID);
            $data['credits'] = (float) $userData['credits'];
            $data['dayWinnings'] = (float) $userData['day_winnings'];
            $data['lifetimeWinnings'] = (float) $userData['lifetime_winnings'];

            echo json_encode($data);

            $em->getConnection()->commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                $em->getConnection()->rollback(); 
                throw $e; 
            }

        // Sample responses that allow you to test your CSS and JS
        // Comment the entire try/catch block above, and uncomment one of these at a time.

        // Regular spin, no prize
        //echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'reels' => array(1, 2.5, 3), 'prize' => null, 'credits' => 99, 'dayWinnings' => 10, 'lifetimeWinnings' => 500));

        // Prize, pays credits only
        //echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'reels' => array(1, 2.5, 3), 'prize' => array('id' => 1, 'payoutCredits' => 10, 'payoutWinnings' => 0), 'credits' => 19, 'dayWinnings' => 00, 'lifetimeWinnings' => 500));

        // Prize, pays winnings only
        //echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'reels' => array(1, 2.5, 3), 'prize' => array('id' => 2, 'payoutCredits' => 0, 'payoutWinnings' => 100), 'credits' => 9, 'dayWinnings' => 100, 'lifetimeWinnings' => 600));

        // Error (logged out)
        //echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'error' => 'loggedOut'));

        // Error (other)
        //echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'error' => 'You do not have enough credits for this spin'));
        //return new Response(json_encode(array('spinData' => $spinData)));
    }


}
```

This is the service that is being used.

```
acme.controller.spin:
    class: Imaginer\IndexBundle\Controller\SpinController
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
```

I am sure the problem is that the doctrine container is not present which is why I am having issues.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Sundar's response work in my case. I had the same problem, and now it works.

When you can't get controller methods anyway, you can inject services what you need in __construct, and give them in service arguments, for example:

in yml:

```
funny.controller.service:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\FunnyController
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

in controller class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

/**
* @Route("/funny", service="funny.controller.service")
*/
class FunnyController extends Controller
{
 private $em;

 public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
```

and later use `$this->em` instead of `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();`

Answer (score -3):

The problem is the container not being injected into the controller here.

Normally symfony does this automatically if youre extending Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller which itself extends Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware.

```
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

 class YourController extends Controller
```

The container is injected into the controller (if not explicitely defined as a service) using setter injection calling the method setContainer() with the container as argument.

Now as you configured your controller as a service you need to add the setContainer call to your service configuration.

```
services:
  database_controller:
    class:  Fuel\FormBundle\Controller\DatabaseController
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
```

Clear your cache afterwards.

CREDITS : nifr :)

Comment: thank you for your back but it's what I do !  but it does not working. you have another idea.